# SSE Instruction To Clone-Expand XMM Register

Tags: x86, sse

Is there any SSE instruction (up to version 4.2) that automatically fills four XMM registers with the value of the four words of another XMM register?

Example: running the instruction on the word `ABCD` would fill four XMM registers: `AAAA`, `BBBB`, `CCCC`, and `DDDD`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe there is a single operation, but four `pshufd` operations (one for each destination) will do the job; see http://lists.apple.com/archives/perfoptimization-dev/2007/Feb/msg00002.html (the first code example, after the `movd` instruction).  There are similar variants of `pshufd` to replicate the other parts of the register.  I believe the constants to use in the instruction are 0, 85, 170, and 255 for the four parts of the register.